# nullpointer when setting combobox index to -1

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, combobox, databound

I have a combobox that gets it data from a database table.

When Selected index changes I want to send the value of the selection to a textbox and then clear the selection.

```
private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainTextBox.Text = ComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
    ComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

This gets the data to the textbox and clears the combobox, but also gives a null pointer exception.

This line by itself works fine:

```
MainTextBox.Text = ComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

This line by itself works fine:

```
ComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set `ComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1` the `ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged` function is called again as the index has been changed.

When the function is called the second time, `NullReferenceException` is thrown as `ComboBox.SelectedValue` is set to `null` at `SelectedIndex` equal to `-1`.

Solution:

```
private void ComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ComboBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        MainTextBox.Text = ComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
        ComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
}
```